# Can sympy arrays be properly sliced after numerical substitutions?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, symbolic-math

Consider this example for sympy:

```
import numpy
from sympy import Array, IndexedBase, symbols

k = symbols('k', positive=True)
M = IndexedBase('M')

M_vals = numpy.array((
    (0, 1, 2),
    (3, 4, 5),
    (6, 7, 8)
))

M[k, 0].subs(M, Array(M_vals)).doit()
```

which prints

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]][k, 0]
```

in a terminal. This indicates that the index `0` is not understood. Otherwise, sympy would have been able to slice out the correct column (the first one) from the matrix resulting in a vector. Is there a way to enable this simplification?

Comment: Why would you expect slicing here? That is not what e.g. `M_vals[i, 0]` would do for `i=0,1,2`.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin That is correct, but it is still possible to simplify the matrix into a vector.

Comment: The expression `M[k, 0]` represents an element of the matrix and not a vector. If you substitute a value for `k` you will get that element.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin But those elements for all `k` form a vector, (0, 3, 6) if I'm not mistaken. So the result could be simplified to `[0, 3, 6][k]`.

Comment: The problem is you believe that M[K,0] first subsets the first column and then subsets the value from the resulting vector. If that was the case, computing would be VERY SLOW. Note that an array is a contiguous memory location. In Python/C++, we use row major. Thus to subset a column is complex as compared to subseting a row. For a value, its straight forward, we compute the index location within the vector and subset accordingly ie `k * NCOL + 0` is the index that will be used.

Comment: Thats why the computer retains the whole vector/array with the subset. Note that most ycas impleentations tend to be close to math but as far as posssible. They have to squeeze out the extra speed.

Comment: You can get the result that you want using slicing to create an intermediate 1D array explicitly `Array(M_vals)[:,0][k]`.

Comment: @Onyambu, this is sympy, so issues of speed and 'row major' don't apply.  We can't assume the sympy Array is stored, or indexed, like numpy or even python lists.

Comment: @hpaulj at some point, if necessary the symbols could be evaluated. thus must follow the logic. Also notice that `M[K,0]` is not identicalto `M[K][0]` or even `M[:,0][K]` ie they both give the same solution but the underlying computation is different. ie `M[K,0]` is equivalent to `m[k*ncols+0]` where m is the vector of the values in flattened M. Note that whatever you need can be obtained by the code shown by @OscarBenjamin

Comment: Also your claim that *this is sympy, so issues of speed and 'row major' don't apply.* is incorrect. Sympy is computationaly intensive. and requires memory and speed. If sympy was easier than numerical, then all problems could be solved in sympy then in the final results we just evaluate it with some given values. But that is not the case.

Comment: What I meant is that when we use `sympy`, we don't normally worry about speed, like we would with numpy.  We live with its slowness.  `M=sp.Array(M_vals)` stores its values in `M._array`, a flat list.  The `M.__getitem__` function (written in python), appears to roughly emulate `ndarray` basic indexing.  It converts the input tuple to a flat list slice.  e.g. `M[:,0]` does `M._array[::3]`. (I'd need to spend more time with `sp.Array` docs and code to be sure.)